# Better alternative to pmap in Clojure for parallelizing moderately inexpensive functions over big data?

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

Using clojure I have a very large amount of data in a sequence and I want to process it in parallel, with a relatively small number of cores (4 to 8).

**The easiest thing to do is use `pmap` instead of `map`**, to map my processing function over the sequence of data. **But the coordination overhead results in a net loss in my case**.

**I think the reason is that `pmap` assumes the function mapped across the data is very costly**. Looking at pmap's source code it appears to construct a `future` for each element of the sequence in turn so each invocation of the function occurs on a separate thread (cycling over the number of available cores).

Here is the relevant piece of pmap's source:

```
(defn pmap
  "Like map, except f is applied in parallel. Semi-lazy in that the
  parallel computation stays ahead of the consumption, but doesn't
  realize the entire result unless required. Only useful for
  computationally intensive functions where the time of f dominates
  the coordination overhead."
  ([f coll]
   (let [n (+ 2 (.. Runtime getRuntime availableProcessors))
         rets (map #(future (f %)) coll)
         step (fn step [[x & xs :as vs] fs]
                (lazy-seq
                 (if-let [s (seq fs)]
                   (cons (deref x) (step xs (rest s)))
                   (map deref vs))))]
     (step rets (drop n rets))))
  ;; multi-collection form of pmap elided
```

In my case the mapped function is not that expensive but sequence is huge (millions of records). I think the cost of creating and dereferencing that many futures is where the parallel gain is lost in overhead.

***Is my understanding of `pmap` correct?***

Is there a better pattern in clojure for this sort of lower cost but massively repeated processing than `pmap`? I am considering chunking the data sequence somehow and then running threads on larger chunks. **Is this a reasonable approach and what clojure idioms would work?**

Comment: don't forget to take advantage of memoization if applicable. http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/memoize

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This question: [how-to-efficiently-apply-a-medium-weight-function-in-parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702705/how-to-efficiently-apply-a-medium-weight-function-in-parallel) also addresses this problem in a very similar context.

The current best answer is to use  `partition` to break it into chunks. then pmap a map function onto each chunk. then recombine the results. map-reduce-style.

Comment: Would I really want to use `pmap` on each chunk? I think that will still create a future per seq item. 
It would make more sense to me to just `map` a `future` onto each chuck.

Comment: the idea is to increase the chunk size so that it beats the coordination overhead while still filling all the cores. Not all data sets have a sweet spot like this.

Comment: Ah-ha. I needed to think at a level of one additional abstraction. I `pmap` a function over the chunks and that function will `map` my processing function over each member of the chunk. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That is the map-reduce style of processing. Split your input to chunks, fire jobs in parallel on each chunk and then join the results. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce . The only question is the size and the number of chunks.

Comment: @Alex Stoddard, thats it. Im fighting back the urge to say that all problems can be solved by one more level of abstraction.

Comment: One has to be careful not to (silently!) skip some of the inputs with `partition` due to the fact that it never produces chunks smaller then specified. E.g. `(partition 5 [1 2])` evaluates to en empty lazy seq! `clojure.contrib.seq-utils/partition-all` (soon to be `clojure.contrib.seq/partition-all`) puts together a short final chunk instead (`((1 2))` with arguments as above).

Comment: (partition 5 5 '() [1 2]) will leave the small-sized chunk on the end and not drop anything.

Comment: Is the Clojure reducers library a better solution now?

Answer (score 5):

Sadly not a valid answer yet, but something to watch for in the future is Rich's work with the fork/join library coming in Java 7.  If you look at his Par branch on github he's done some work with it, and last I had seen the early returns were amazing.

Example of Rich trying it out.

http://paste.lisp.org/display/84027

Comment: Actually I have discovered this can be tried now with Java6, the Clojure "par" branch from github and the jsr166y.jar file that Rich Hickey made available at: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/richhickey/clojure/jsr166y.jar

Comment: Ohhh really?  May have to give that a look, as Par looks amazing.  Thanks for the tip, as I missed this.

Comment: Is this what eventually became the reducers library?

Answer (score 2):

The fork/join work mentioned in earlier answers on this and similar threads eventually bore fruit as the [reducers](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html) library, which is probably worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of map/reduce implemented by hand. Also take a look at [swarmiji](http://github.com/amitrathore/swarmiji) framework.

"A distributed computing system that helps writing and running Clojure code in parallel - across cores and processors"

Comment: swarmiji if a library for distributed computing in Clojure. I got the impression this quiestion was focusing more on single-system-parallel-exacution.